# PyMongo query field of documents

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In my DynamoDB every document has several fields, one of the fields is a document called "engines" that holds several documents (all the engines) that hold several fields, as the picture shows below:

[image]

I would like to get all the couples of (engine,definitions) that their definition date is greater than a specific date.

I tried:

```
cursor=collection.find(
                     {'engines': { "$elemMatch" : 
                                  { "definitions" : 
                                   {'$gt': startdate} } } }
                                    ,{'engines':{'$elemMatch':1}},{'engines':{'$elemMatch':{'definitions':1}}}  )
```

but I get:
TypeError: skip must be an instance of int

Can someone help with the query?

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed up the closing `}` and ended up passing `{'engines':{'$elemMatch':{'definitions':1}}}` as a [`skip` argument value](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find).

I think you meant:

```
cursor = collection.find(
    {
        'engines': {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "definitions": {
                    '$gt': startdate
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        'engines': {
            '$elemMatch': {
                'definitions': 1
            }
        }
    }
)
```